# Proof the recurrence relation of order statistics using induction

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, recurrence

I read order statistics from the book The Design and Analysis of Computer Algorithms", by Aho, Hopcroft, Ullman, Addison-Wesley

As per the algorithm the recurrence relation given

T(n)<= cn for n<=49 .....1

T(n)<= T(n/5) + T(3n/4) + cn   for n>=50 .....2

How can I prove it by induction T(n)<= 20cn?

I have two more questions

For the 1st equation why they define n<=49 and for the 2nd equation n>=50

Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it's a better fit for https://cs.stackexchange.com since it's not a programming or implementation issue.

Comment: There is a pseudo code associated with the recurrence. I mention the book name.. so I did not write the code as it will be redundant to mention it. So don't close it.

Comment: Pseudo-code or not, you're not askiing about an implementation issue.  That's why it's better suited to cs.stackexchange.